# Why is that when we are adding to both sides of an equation we don't add to every single term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have all heard the age old expression of what you do to one equation, you must do this to the other equation.
Lets take an example equation of $$3x - 2 = 4x +5$$
when solving this equation you would add two to both sides and get
$$3x = 4x + 7$$
my question is why is that when we are adding to both sides that we don't add to every single term, but when we do a multiplication or division operation we would multiply / divide every term.
Also another question, in essence when we are doing something to both sides can we treat each side of the equation like a term. So in essence for the equation when we are dividing by both sides is it basically: $$1/2(3x-2) = 1/2(4x+5)$$, meaning when we do something to both sides do we treat the equation like a term? What exactly is happening behind the scenes? Why is it that you multiply every term but you don't add every single term?

Comment: You always treat the original quantities as one term. Compare for example $\,(3x-2)\color{red}{+2}=(4x+5)\color{red}{+2}\;$ to $\;(3x-2)\color{red}{\,\times\,2}=(4x+5)\color{red}{\,\times\,2}$. It's just that, when you add, the parentheses are (usually) unnecessary.

Comment: would another person like to confirm this, if this is true it would make solving complex equations a lot easier

Comment: It is certainly true.

Comment: @MarlonHenderson I recommend you avoid using the word "complex" because it is usually reserved for a special type of numbers of "complex numbers" (Wikipedia for more).

Answer (score 2):

[symplectomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23611/symplectomorphic) provided an excellent answer. However, I want to add some visuals and word it a little differently hoping that it maybe easier to understand.

The key point to understand an equation is to not think about it as a formula, but a balanced scale.[image]

Imagine the picture above is a top-view angle of a balanced scale. We say $C=D$.

Now what happens if you add $M$ to *both sides*?[image]

You can imagined the scale must be still balanced, right? After all, both sides are added the same weight! So, $C+M = D+M$. [image]

What if you divide the left side of the scale into two parts A and B. Intuitively, $A+B = D$.

What happens if you add $M$ to *every term*?[image]

I think it makes lots of sense that the scale cannot be balanced: You added 2 $M$s on the left and only 1 the right. So $A+M + B+M \neq D+M$

This even makes more sense if you have lots of terms on one side and very few on another, like this:[image]

I hope you get the picture; there's no way two sides could be still balanced if you add the same thing to *every term*.

But why does multiplying and dividing every term work? In short, **it is a coincident**. As demonstrated above, things only work well if you apply stuff to *both sides*, so technically, when you have $a=b+c$ you would turn it into $na=n(b+c)$, not $na=nb+nc$. Why writing it as $na = nb + nc$ is still correct has been discussed by symplectomorphic, so I won't touch that topic.

In conclusion, when dealing with equation, you want to imagine it as a scale and **always stress *both sides* equally** to keep it balanced. Some special method of stressing (like multiplying) may allow you to stress *every term*, but this property is special and do not occur commonly in math.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question: “Why is that when we are adding to both sides that we don't add to every single term, but when we do a multiplication or division operation we would multiply / divide every term [...] Why is it that you multiply every term but you don't add every single term?”

The short answer is that multiplication and division are special because of the distributive law: they *distribute over addition and subtraction*.

In general, when you apply an arithmetic operation to both sides of an equation, you do *not* apply it to each “term” on each side (assuming the expressions have terms at all — parts that are added or subtracted).

For example, if $a+b=c$ and you want to “square both sides,” you *do not* square each individual term to get $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Rather, you square the entire expression: $(a+b)^2=c^2$. The reason these two equations are not equivalent is that *exponentiation doesn’t distribute over addition and subtraction*. Most arithmetic operations are like this. Taking the absolute value, taking the sine, taking the square root — none of these operations distributes over addition and subtraction. Therefore, when you apply one of these operations to both sides of an equation, you **cannot** apply them to each individual term.

But the operations of multiplication and division are special. They *do* distribute over addition and subtraction. Multiplying both sides of $a+b=c$ by $5$ gives $5(a+b)=5c$. But the left side is in fact $5a+5b$ because of the distributive property.

In summary: you may only apply an operation to each individual term of an expression if the operation distributes over addition and subtraction.

Caveat lector: most operations *do not* have such a distributive property. That includes the operations of addition and subtraction themselves. Adding $1$ to $a+b$ is *not* the same as $a+1+b+1$, and that’s because addition does not distribute over itself.